# How to remove dropdown selection in Vue on a specific condition?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am creating a dropdown selection (visit status) which consists of `pending`,`canceled` `rejected` and `approved`. So when it is approved, i want the dropdown selection to show canceled and rejected selection only. The `this.inputs.visit_status.choices` is consisted of array and object that represent visit status choices. Each array consists of `display name` and `value` For example, `display name` equal to `PENDING` and value equal to `pending`. Is it possible to remove the specific array if visit status is approved and show `canceled` and `rejected` value only ?

`Array Example`

```
0: {__ob__: Observer} ( pending)
1: {__ob__: Observer} ( approved)
2: {__ob__: Observer} (canceled)
3: {__ob__: Observer} (rejected)
```

`Dropdown Selection`

```
      this.$set(this.inputs.visit_status, "item_text", "display_name")
      this.$set(this.inputs.visit_status, "item_value", "value")
      this.$set(this.inputs.visit_status, "items", this.inputs.visit_status.choices)
      this.$set(this.visitStatusOriginal, "visit_status", item.visit_status)
      if (item.visit_status) {
        this.$set(this.inputs.visit_status, "value", item.visit_status)
        this.$set(this.inputs.visit_status, "tmp_value", {
          "display_name": item.visit_status.toUpperCase(),
          "value": item.visit_status
          })
      }
```

What i had tried :

I try to set a condition if the visit status value is equal to approved , i set the value according to the value but it only show one option only which is rejected only. The result that I want is to show `cancel` and `reject` options. Is there any way to improve this code ?

```
 if (item.visit_status == 'approved'){
          this.$set(this.inputs.visit_status, "items", this.inputs.visit_status.choices[2])
          this.$set(this.inputs.visit_status, "items", this.inputs.visit_status.choices[3])
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your description the `items` variable is expected to be an array.
What your code does is set a single option at a time to `items` instead of an array.

Please try the following code:

```
if (item.visit_status == 'approved') {
    this.$set(this.inputs.visit_status, "items", [this.inputs.visit_status.choices[2], this.inputs.visit_status.choices[3]]);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much , it works.  does this considered hardcoded ? can it be improved ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by heard-coded. One suggestion I have is reading about the need for `this.$set`; you can actually use regular variable assignment in *most* places and achieve the same result.